# How do I get the number of uncompleted Todo items?

Tags: javascript

How do I get the number of uncompleted Todo items?
I am using the `itemsLeft()` function to generate the items that are left.
All the filters function work just fine but I am stuck when it come to generating the number of uncompleted items.
I need to be able to able to generate the number of uncompleted items and pass it somewhere into the HTML.
Here is the part of the script file containing the filter code.

```
//FILTERS AND COMPLETED ITEMS SECTION

function completedItem(event) {
    event.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("completed");
    messageAlert("Item Completed", "success");
}

//Show Completed Items Only 

const filterOptions = container.querySelectorAll(".item--filter");

function filterItems(event) {
    const items = listContainer.childNodes;

    items.forEach((item)=> {
        switch(event.target.innerHTML) {
            case "All":
                if(clearButton.clicked === true) {
                    clearItems()
                } {
                    item.style.display = "flex";
                }
                break;
            case "Completed":
                if(item.children[0].children[1].classList.contains("completed")) {
                    item.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    item.style.display = "none";
                }
                break;
            case "Active":
                if(!item.children[0].children[1].classList.contains("completed")) {
                    item.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    item.style.display = "none";
                }
                break;
        }
    })
}

filterOptions.forEach((filterOption)=> {
    filterOption.addEventListener("click", filterItems);
})

// Items Left and Clear Completed Items
const itemsLeftButton = container.querySelector(".filter__items--left");
const clearButton = container.querySelector(".filter__completed--clear");
const itemsLeftInnerHTML = container.querySelector("#left");



const itemsLeft = ()=> {
    const items = listContainer.childNodes;
    
    items.forEach((item)=> {
        if(item.children[0].children[1].classList.contains("completed")) {
            item.style.display = "none";
        }
        
    })
}

itemsLeftButton.addEventListener("click", itemsLeft)

const clearItems = ()=>{
    const items = listContainer.childNodes;
    items.forEach((item)=> {
        if(item.children[0].children[1].classList.contains("completed")) {
            item.style.display = "none";
        } 
    })
}

clearButton.addEventListener("click", clearItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the to do list items are stored in an array you can use the [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function to count the total number and subtract the counted number of completed items as well

Comment: I tried that but it was giving me undefined.